C++ padding of struct still occurs when using #pragma pack
I am trying to implement a 24-bit integral datatype using a c++ struct. I want its size to be 24 bits / 3 bytes -- not padded into a 4 byte int. I am using Visual Studio Community 2019's compiler.
I have tried using #pragma pack to prevent this as shown below, but sizeof( int24 ) still returns 4.
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct int24{
    unsigned int data : 24;
};

#pragma pack(pop)

How can I get the struct to have a size of 3 bytes? I want to avoid using an array of unsigned chars if possible.

I believe #pragma pack is only ralated to adding padding bytes between members. See the documentation.

@wohlstad does #pragma pack differ from gcc's __attribute((__packed__))__ in that regard? since that seems to be able to produce structs without external padding (via)

Your packing would lead to unaligned memory access, something not supported by the C++ virtual machine.

looks like a byte array is the solution then

@DavidStuckey I am not familiar with gcc's version. I am also not 100% about VS, which is why I wrote a comment starting with "I believe".

Also bitfields in C++ will NOT result in a speficic number of bits being allocated. The number of bits actually used is implementation defined (and varies from compiler to compiler). The only promise the C++ standard makes is that your bitfield (:24) arithmetically behaves as if it where an integer with 24 bits. The compiler is free to still use 32 bits of memory space.

According to my understanding of the #pragma pack documentation it is only related to adding padding bytes between (or after) members in a structure, and not to the size allocated for a member itself.
In order to achieve what you want you can use a struct holding a std::array of 3 bytes, with accessors for converting a uint32_t value to/from it:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

struct int24 {
    explicit int24(uint32_t value)
    {
        set(value);
    }

    void set(uint32_t value)
    {
        bytes[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(value & 0x000000ff);
        bytes[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>((value & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
        bytes[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>((value & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
    }

    uint32_t get()
    {
        uint32_t value = bytes[0] + (bytes[1] << 8) + (bytes[2] << 16);
        return value;
    }

private:
    std::array<uint8_t,3> bytes;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(int24) << std::endl;
    int24 i24{ 12345 };
    std::cout << i24.get();
}

Output:
3
12345

Live demo

You can consider to add copy/move and assignment operators according to your needs.
You can also consider to add validation in the set method that the uint32_t value can actually be represented using 24 bits (using an exception or some other error handling method).
Lastly you can add accessor methods for converting to/from other integral types.

Note that this solution is dependant on the Endianness of your system.

Thank you for your help! It looks like I'm going to have to use a byte array after all, just makes it a little more difficult to do the operator overloading.

@DavidStuckey Here's a start: example

@TedLyngmo nice generalization !

@wohlstad Thanks. I realize that it does however store more information than wanted if B % CHAR_BIT != 0. One would have to shave off the extra bits of information in the constructor.

It annoyed me so here's a sligthly cleaned-up version to shave off those extra bits: demo :-)

@TedLyngmo even nicer :-)  I think you should consider to post it as an answer (my upvote is guaranteed).

@wohlstad Thanks! Nah, I'm happy with my upvote on your answer, which is exactly what I had in mind to start with. I just went nuts with it :-)
